# how can I add a background image to my html inside a Div without adding more classes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm working on my project which involves working with a map and adding locations inside pop-ups. In those locations, I added the name of the location, an image, and the address. Unfortunately, the image doesn't appear. I've tried several source links but it either doesn't show or it shows a very small image that appears to have been cut. Here's what I've done so far:

//javascript (This is just one of the locations but I have a lot more)

```
var restaurantMarkers = [
      {
        coords: { lat: 59.9178541, lng: 10.7339675 },
        content:
          '<div class="marker"><h6>Den Glade Gris</h6><img src="../images/restaurant1.jpg" alt="1" /><br><p>St. Olavs Gate 33</p></div>',
      },
```

//CSS (if I add backgroung-image to the css the image appears, but that means I would have to create several classes to add a background image to my locations and I have around 60 of them.

```
.marker{
    
    width: 120px;
    height: 110px;
}
```

Comment: You can just inline the background-image CSS on the marker: `<div class="marker" style="background-image: url(../images/restaurant1.jpg)">`

Comment: @Reyno the image still doesn't appear

Comment: The problem may be the image route, Is the JS in a separate file?

Comment: @AndreiaGaspar Are you sure the image path is correct, are there errors in the console?

Comment: @Reyno ok here's the werid thing, I added what you recomended

Comment: @Reyno

<div class="marker" style="background-image: url(../images/restaurant1.jpg)">

and when I inspect if I check out the background-image the image appears.

I just got more confused

Comment: @Reyno nevermind. the image was in the .marker in the css, but that's not what I want. so I deleted it and now the link is in the div not in the css. So the image is not appearing again

Comment: @PeterSH yes the js is in a separate file

Comment: @PeterSH was propably asking for whether image file is in the same directory, because if not you need to pay attention to the path because this is almost always the isssue when your img does not show on the page. I would move the img file to the same directory as the js file and try if it wil show

Comment: @JacckMark the images are in the following link

assets > images > restaurant1.jpg

and the js file 

assets > js > googlemaps.js

Comment: so your path looks fine. And what about the developer tools in chrome if you are trying to inspect this element?

Comment: @JacckMark what do you mean? I can inspect it yeah but nothing happens. I've tried changing it but it's still not working

Comment: @JacckMark maybe you can check it in the deployed version of it here:

https://gaspar91.github.io/mlsp2/

Comment: @AndreiaGaspar You should try changing the path based on the location of your HTML. Since it gets loaded in the browser. Meaning if your index.html is at the same level as your assets folder. Change the path to `/assets/images/restaurant1.jpg` or try it will the full url (including the http part)

Answer (score 1):

The routing in separate JS files start from the location where the JS files was "included" from. So if your file structure looks like:

```
root/
├── index.html
└── assets/
    └── images/
      └── restaurant1.jpg
    └── js/
      └── googlemaps.js
```

And you're javascript file is linked in `index.html`, you need to start your routing from there (e.g., `background-image: url(assets/images/restaurant1.jpg)`).

Or if you're file structure looks like:

```
root/
├── index.html
└── views/
    └── map.html
└── assets/
    └── images/
      └── images.jpg
    └── js/
      └── googlemaps.js
```

And you're javascript file is linked in `view/map.html`, you need to start your routing from there (e.g., `background-image: url(../assets/images/restaurant1.jpg)`).

Keep in mind, these are examples, your file structure is probably different.

Comment: thank you for this, but the image is still not appearing. I only get an icon of an image that is ripped

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser console? Chrome & Edge: F12, firefox: Ctrl+Shift+J

Answer (score 0):

ok so this is what I did

```
background-image: url(assets/images/restaurant1.jpg);
```

with this the image appears, the problem now is that it's repeating so I tried this:

```
background-image: url(assets/images/restaurant1.jpg) no-repeat;
```

but when I add "no-repeat" the image is gone again

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out! Thanks everyone!

here's what I did:

```
<div class="marker" style="background: url(assets/images/restaurant1.jpg) no-repeat center">
```